# html in jsp tag

Tags: html, jsp, tags

Html in jsp tag

```
 <jsp:setProperty name="mail" property="message" value="<html> <body><h1>Welcome</h1> <br/> <table cellpadding=\"6\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"1\">
                   <tr><td style=\"text-align: left;font-weight: bold\">User Name:</td><td> +email+</td></tr> <tr><td style=\"text-align: left;font-weight: bold\">Password:</td><td>+pass+</td></tr>
                  </table></body></html>"/>
```

not displaying in tabular format
but showing the whole html tag

Comment: What does it say when you take HTML source of the page?

Answer (score 1):

In XML, double quotes aren't escaped using a backslash. They're escaped using `&quot;`.

Comment: can u provide me an example plz

Comment: Replace every `\"` with `&quot;`. And specify WHICH error you get instead of just saying "giving error". The error message contains meaningful information.

Comment: not getting any error but it is not showing in tabular format
but showing the complete html tag

Comment: What isn't showing? The only code you show is not displaying anything.

Comment: i want the thing written in value in tabular format as in html
but i wrote this its showing the whole <html> tags

Comment: I can't tell what you did wrong, since I don't see your code.

Comment: So, I repeat. The code above sets a property. It doesn't display anything. The problem is in the code displaying this property, that you haven't shown.